# Mail going to inbox but cannot display sender name

Tags: php, email

I want to send to mail to user for any update.

My first tried as below, here all mail goes to spam folder but here sender name display well.

This code is

```
$headers = "From: Sender Name <info@senderweb.com >\r\n" .
    "Reply-To: info@ senderweb.com\r\n" .
    'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
    'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
```

After prevent goes to spam folder, my below code make all mail goes well at inbox but here sender name display server name something like senderwe@server1.server.com.

I found this report at track delivary of cpanel : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128 CV=yes: SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM:< senderwe@server1.server.com > SIZE=3829: 553 5.7.1 [BL21] Connections will not be accepted from ###.72.###.129, because the ip is in Spamhaus's list; s

```
$headers = "From: Sender Name <info@senderweb.com >";
$headers = "Reply-To: info@ senderweb.com \r\n" .
    'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
    'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
```

I also look at Spamhaus's list by this ip, where I found my ip is listed in the XBL.

Please where is my problem here to display sender name at inbox?

Full Code:

```
$subject = "My subject";

$message .= "<html>";
$message .= "<head>";
$message .= "<style type=\"text/css\" media=\"screen\">";
$message .= "a:link, a:visited {color:#A0C804; text-decoration:none;}";
$message .= "a:hover {color:#339933; text-decoration:none;}";
$message .= "body {background-color:#FFFFFF;";
$message .= "font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;";
$message .= "color:#000000;";
$message .= "font-size:12px;}";
$message .= "p.general {font-size: 14px;";
$message .= "line-height: 16px;";
$message .= "font-weight: normal;";
$message .= "padding-right:20px;";
$message .= "padding-left:17px;";
$message .= "margin-bottom:3px;}";
$message .= ".page {background-color:#ff0000;";
$message .= "padding:0px;";
$message .= "width:100%;}";
$message .= ".content {width:100%;";
$message .= "height:auto;";
$message .= "background-color:#FFFFFF;";
$message .= "padding:10px;";
$message .= "border:#ECEBEB;}";
$message .= "span.prospan {font-size: 14px;";
$message .= "line-height: 16px;";
$message .= "padding-left:20px;";
$message .= "margin-bottom:10px;}";
$message .= "p.proitem {font-size: 14px;";
$message .= "margin-bottom:10px;";
$message .= "padding-left:17px;}";
$message .= "p.tota {color: #ff0000;";
$message .= "padding-left:17px;";
$message .= "font-size: 14px;";
$message .= "margin-bottom:20px;";
$message .= "font-weight: bold;}";
$message .= "p.soong {color: #000000;";
$message .= "padding-left:17px;";
$message .= "margin-bottom:10px;";
$message .= "font-size: 14px;";
$message .= "font-weight: bold;}";
$message .= "p.foot {color: #000000;";
$message .= "margin-bottom:10px;";
$message .= "padding-left:17px;";
$message .= "font-size: 14px;}";
$message .= "</style>";
$message .= "<body>";
$message .= "<div class=\"page\">";
$message .= "<div class=\"content\">";
$message .= "<table width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" bordercolor=\"#ECEBEB\">";
$message .= "<tr>";
$message .= "<td style=\"text-align:left;\" bgcolor=\"#FF6699\"><img src=\"http://www.myweb.com.au/images/logo.png\" width=\"99\" height=\"83\"  style=\"padding:15px;\" /></td>";
$message .= "<td style=\"text-align:right;\" bgcolor=\"#FF6699\"><h2 style=\"color:#ffffff;padding:20px;\" >Web name</h2></td>";
$message .= "</tr>";
$message .= "<tr>";
$message .= "<td><table width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">";
$message .= "</tr>";
$message .= "<tr>";
$message .= "<td width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"20\" align=\"left\"><br>";
$message .= "<p class=\"general\"><b>Congratulation ! </b></p><br>";
$message .= "<p class=\"general\">Dear <b>".$my_name."</b> ,</p><br>";
$message .= "<p class=\"general\">Massage to clint.</p><br>";
$message .= "</td>";
$message .= "</tr>";
$message .= "</table>"; 
$message .= "</div>";
$message .= "</div>";
$message .= "</body>";
$message .= "</html>";

$headers = "From: Sender Name <info@senderweb.com >";
$headers = "Reply-To: info@senderweb.com \r\n" .
    'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
    'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";   

        mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: Can you provide the full part of code and are you using php mail function?

Comment: If you find your IP has been listed by XBL, your system is very likely compromised by a virus via mail, web, or other download. To fix it, you need to find and close any open SOCKS, Wingate or HTTP type proxies. Many viruses install open proxies and other Trojan Horse or "backdoor" malware on systems, so you should download a copy of stinger for Windows from www.nai.com, and fix anything it finds.

Comment: Thank you, Update with full code

Comment: I checked with stinger but nothing found in my pc.

Comment: check sender details in php.ini and sendmail.ini

Answer (score 0):

Send a delist request for sender address. Any local cPanel user can use the 127.0.0.1 IP address to send mail without authentication. This can make it difficult for system administrators to determine which cPanel account sent the mail, especially when a malicious user spoofs an email address to disguise the origin of the email.
To require cPanel & WHM to put the actual sender in the header, enable the Experimental: Rewrite From: header to match actual sender option in WHM's  Exim Configuration Manager interface (Home >> Exim Service Configuration >> Exim Configuration Manager). Check here https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Prevent+Email+Abuse